# File object from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to create a file object from an image located at a specific url. I'm downloading the file with Net Http:

```
img = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('https://prium-solutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/rails-1.png'))
file = File.read(img.body)
```

However, I get `ArgumentError: string contains null byte` when trying to read the file and store in into the `file` variable.

How can I do this without having to store it locally ?

Comment: Did the solution work?

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari it might, but I specified in the question "without having to store it locally", and since you're using a tempfile, it didn't fit

Comment: it won't get stored locally. You should try it once

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari a tempfile requires a tmp folder to store, which on platforms like Heroku, aren't reliable. So I don't know how you call this, but I call this "storing locally"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `File` deals with reading from storage, it's really not applicable here. The `read` method is expecting you to hand it a location to read from, and you're passing in binary data.

If you have a situation where you need to interface with a library that expects an object that is streaming, you can wrap the string body in a [StringIO](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) object:

```
file = StringIO.new(img)
# you can now call file.read, file.seek, file.rewind, etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.
From this, how can I get the same output as if I was doing this with a local file:
file = File.open("/path/to/image.jpg")

I need the same object, only difference is that mine is through a URL. With your answer, I'm not getting a file object

Comment: @GrahamSlick The only tangible difference between StringIO and File in application is that File also has information related to the filesystem (e.g. permissions, path) that are irrelevant when you don't have an actual file. Seriously, try using what I gave you. If you run into an error, share. If this is all confusing, google “duck typing”.